# Elasticsearch Java API access source when Exception is thrown

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I am learning the Java RestHighLevelClient but I can't find the answer to this question.

When you submit a REST request to something where a document is not found you will see something like this:

```
$ curl localhost:9200/customer/_doc/1?pretty
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "index_not_found_exception",
        "reason" : "no such index [customer]",
        "resource.type" : "index_expression",
        "resource.id" : "customer",
        "index_uuid" : "_na_",
        "index" : "customer"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "index_not_found_exception",
    "reason" : "no such index [customer]",
    "resource.type" : "index_expression",
    "resource.id" : "customer",
    "index_uuid" : "_na_",
    "index" : "customer"
  },
  "status" : 404
}
```

However in the Java client you code something like this:

```
    GetRequest request = new GetRequest(INDEX, ROOT);
    GetResponse response = null;
    try {
        response = client.get(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
         // do something with the IOException
    } catch (ElasticsearchException ese) {
         // where is the response source?
    }
```

So if the document is not found, you get the **ElasticsearchException** in which case the local variable **response** is null.  So where do you get
the source document that was present at the low level?  (Preferably as a Map).

Comment: what do you mean by source document that was present at the low level?

Comment: @AmitKhandelwal Look at the output of the `curl` command.   It is a JS object that has all the information you would ever want about the error.   How do I get that in the Java code I posted?

Answer (score 1):

You can get to the source of the response at the low level via the suppressesed exceptions in the `ElasticsearchException`.

```java
Throwable[] suppressed = ese.getSuppressed();
if (suppressed.length > 0 && suppressed[0] instanceof ResponseException) {
    ResponseException re = (ResponseException) suppressed[0];
    Response response = re.getResponse();
}
```